# R - Problems with Time Series Graphs and ACF

Tags: r, time-series, advanced-custom-fields, forecasting, arima

I'm pretty new to R, I'm trying to do some ARIMA forecasting on my time series graph, but my AFC plot doesn't look right..it may be the way I've plotted my ts

Here's my code for the TS:

```
library(tseries)
library(xts)

data1<-read.csv("~/Desktop/SQN_Yr.csv",sep=",", header=TRUE,na.strings="..")
data1[,1] <- as.Date(data1[,1]) 
class(data1$Monthly) #validating data.type
data1$Number<-ts(data1$Number, start=c(2005,1), frequency = 12)
plot(data1$Number)
acf(data1$Number, lag.max=NULL)
```

Here's my TS graph

[image]

Here's my ACF plot..

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible you're actually looking for pacf()? The first value of the acf graph with always be 1 (since it's the correlation of every item with itself).

Comment: Yep, i will be looking at the pacf() as well, but I think there's something wrong with the lags, i'm not sure it should be between 0 and 1.5, given my time series spans from 2005 to 2016..

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong, since it's a correlation, it must be less than 1. Looks almost like white noise to me.

Comment: I agree that the correlation is between 0 and 1, but i'm not sure about the lags, I thought it should at least be in whole numbers and not between 0 and 1.5?